# Show alert dialog after splash screen once only

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to show an **Alert Dialog** after splash screen when user opens App for the first time. I implemented *Splash Screen* using [this link](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/create-a-splash-screen-on-android-the-right-way-93d6fb444857).
Guide me how to do this ?

**Style**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
</style>
```

**background.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/splash" />
</item>
```

**SplashActivity.class**

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save an initialization value in a persistent way such as a database or, simpler, in SharedPreferences. Check this value on startup. Like:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean isInitialized = sharedPref.getBoolean("INIT_STATE", false);

if (!isInitialized) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Prompt message")
            .setMessage("Your message")
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("INIT_STATE", true);
                    editor.apply();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // do nothing
                }
            })
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .show();
} else {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Of course this code is a guide, you should add error checking and avoid duplicate code wherever possible, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your SplashActivity, you can check if is the first time the user is oppening your app.

You can create a sharedPreference to save when the user openned your app for the first time.

I hope you understand. :)